# TypeScript Type Narrowing Error with forEach

Tags: typescript

Please help me to understand how TS narrow types. I [have](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAUIxAGwFMpEIBDMAQWhgDcKpjEBeRKAJxGIG5d8iANoByFHBEBdAHQpOAUQoQAFmkxsAfDkEFKNOo2ZtkFQgGc+ggL4YBuhGbglphOAHM0e2rEPEM-KwFxTF4gA) a simple `foo` function which has `forEach` iterator over an arbitrary array. It's clear that `console.log` will log `false` after executing this code, but TS insists that it's `true`, which is wrong.

My expectation is if TS can't handle `forEach` or similar functions because of possible asynchronity, then it should suggest `boolean`. This situation really frustrates me and slows my productivity, because I need to re-check everything 10 times to prove that TS is wrong and my code is correct.

```
function foo() {
  let canActivate = true;

  ['foo'].forEach(() => {
    canActivate = false;
  })

  console.log(canActivate);
}

foo();
```

[image: ts playground]

Comment: What is the type of `canActivate` inside the `forEach` callback?

Comment: Also, what version of TypeScript are you using? Have you filed this as an issue in their GitHub repo?

Comment: try to use `var` instead of `let`

Comment: @Dai `canActivate` type in `forEach` is the same as outside, because it's the same variable. TS version is 3.9.2. No, i didn't fill the issue, because my suggestion that it is not a bug and can be somehow explained.

Comment: @EugeneKarataev So inside the callback it says the type of `canActivate` is `true` and not `boolean`? It should give you an error for assigning `false` to it then.

Comment: @AlvinStefanus I think we should not use `var` in modern code. Anyway, with `var` the suggestion is the same: `(local var) canActivate: true`

Comment: @Dai oh, I'm sorry, I was wrong, inside the `forEach` the TS suggesion is `boolean`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This excellent blog post](https://herringtondarkholme.github.io/2017/02/04/flow-sensitive/) explains that this is a feature, not a bug. I'll quote a big chunk here (emphasis added):

**Example**

```
let a: number | null = 42

makeSideEffect()

a // is `a` still a number?

function makeSideEffect() {   
  // omitted... 
}
```

> ...
>
> One might ask [the] compiler to infer what `makeSideEffect` does since we can
> provide the source of the function. However this is not practically
> feasible because of ambient function and (possibly polymorphic)
> recursion. **Compiler will be trapped in infinite loops if we instruct
> it to infer arbitrary deep functions, as halting problem per se.**
>
> So a realistic compiler must guess what a function does by a
> consistent strategy. Naturally we have two alternatives:
>
> - **Assume every function does not have relevant side effect**: e.g.
>   assignment like `a = null`. We call this optimistic.
> - Assume every
>   function does have side effect. We call this strategy pessimistic.
>
> Spoiler: **TypeScript uses optimistic strategy.**

---

One more short excerpt:

> No keyword will tell [the] compiler whether callback function will be called
> *immediately*, nor static analysis will tell the behavior of a function:
> `setTimeout` and `forEach` is the same in the view of compiler.
>
> So the following example will not compile.

```
var a: string | number = 42 // smart cast to number
someArray.forEach(() => {
  a.toFixed() // error, string | number does not have method `toFixed`
})
```

---

So there you have it. The post also explains that there is *no solution* to get TypeScript to recognize the side effects of a `forEach` function, or any function for that matter other than immediately invoked functions. That means you can either:

- Use a [regular for loop](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAUIxAGwFMpEIBDMAQWhgDcKpjEBeRKAJxGIG5d8yOJ0RoSZGIjjBEAbQDkKOPIC6WPAQKUadRszbIKhAM59BAXwFaExuCQB0hOAHM0AImrBmnNwBpyVLSwesQY-Ja4Spi8QA) instead of `forEach`, which causes the final `canActivate` to be inferred correctly as `boolean` rather than `true`.
- Use immediately invoked functions when possible. Or...
- Stick to functional programming (FP) paradigms when using [FP-style features](https://deepu.tech/functional-programming-in-typescript/) like `map`, `filter`, `forEach`, etc. That means aim for immutability, no side effects, and so on.

All in all, not great news. Hopefully in the future TypeScript will gain some sort of feature that will allow us to warn the compiler when a function is modifying a certain variable—at least to prevent a premature assumption that something which started off as true will always remain so.

Comment: Wow, fantastic response, thanks a lot! It's an eye opener for me that TS doesn't look inside callback functions even if they are executed in sync with execution flow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have interrupted type inference somewhere in the middle by `console.log` side effect) [Please look here at line 11](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAUIxAGwFMpEIBDMAQWhgDcKpjEBeRKAJxGIG5d8iANoByFHBEBdAHQpOAUQoQAFmkxsAfDkEFKNOo2ZtkFQgGc+ggL4YBBTqRCcke2rEOWrAiAjNkHZiCEZOzimLxAA)

Also, TS does not infer types from side-effects like forEach. It is by design. There is a bunch of TS features to help TS to infer types. Look at this article
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: If you mouse over `canActivate` on line 8 in your example, you'll get `let canActivate: true`, which is wrong, so it's not because of `console.log`.

Comment: IMHO in such cases it is better to define types explicitly.
`let canActivate: boolean = true;`
What do you think?

Comment: But explicit `boolean` doesn't work in this case as well. TS narrows `boolean` to `true`.