# TS2339: Property does not exist on type 'never' OR TS2454: Variable is used before being assigned

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am stuck with typescript error which I can't solve. Here is a small example:

```
interface User {
  name?: string;
}
let user: User;
[1].map((el) => {
  user = {
    name: 'bob',
  };
});
user?.name;
```

In this case I have an error

> TS2454: Variable 'user' is used before being assigned.

When I try to remove the type of var:

```
interface User {
  name?: string;
}
let user;
[1].map((el) => {
  user = {
    name: 'bob',
  };
});
user?.name;
```

I have the next error:

> TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.

Have no idea how to solve this. Seems that typescript doesn't understand at all that variable could be initialized from callback function.

Here my tsconfig files:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strict": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "outDir": ".next",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./nest-next/examples/basic",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./typings"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": ["./pages/**/*", "./src/**/*", "./ui/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and second one:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": ".next/production-server",
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": false,
    "allowJs": false
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Very hope that somebody knows a solution, because I can't find it for two days..

UPD: more real example:

```
interface Directory {
  name: string;
  children: Directory[];
}
const rootDir: Directory = {
  name: 'root',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'downloads',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'photos',
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const forEachDir = (
  parentDir: Directory,
  callback: (parentDir: Directory) => void,
) => {
  callback(parentDir);
  for (const child of parentDir.children) {
    forEachDir(child, callback);
  }
};

// we want to find an object which represents 'photos' directory.
let photosDir;
forEachDir(rootDir, (dir: Directory) => {
  if (dir.name === 'photos') {
    photosDir = dir;
  }
});
console.log(photosDir?.name); //TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

Comment: Is `[1].map((el) => {
  user = {
    name: 'bob',
  };
});` your actual code? If so, it doesn't make any sense - if not, can you post your real code, to demonstrate what you're trying to do here? I'm sure there's a good solution, but your actual current objective with that part is unclear to me

Comment: No, my code is absolutely different. I just found that if you initialize 'user' inside 'if' -> typescript understand that possibly some value will be assigned. But if you assign inside some callback-function (for example callback from Array.map) -> typescript doesn't assume at all that a some value could be assigned to this variable

Comment: @CertainPerformance, and in my code I often have 'let something; difficult find construction (with callbacks); if (something) { then ... }'

Comment: Yep, TS doesn't check that the callback runs. But if your code typings depend on such a strange thing, the code is almost certainly in need of refactoring.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, not sure that it is bad code style. For example imagine nested structure of directories: every directory has a name and nested directories. And you need to find a directory with name 'photos'. If found -> use instance of this directory somehow. How would you do it?

Comment: Sure, that sounds pretty easy - can you post the actual code that does that operation in the question so we have a baseline to go off of?

Comment: That happens because the callback might run at some later point and does definitely run before you use your variable. That's exactly the error you are seeing. Assign a default value to use or use a null check. Or switch to a normal for loop.

Comment: @pascalpuetz if I assign 'null' as default, then after 'map' typescript think that 'user' could be only 'null' and will not allow to use 'user.name' field anyway.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, sure, I've added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been discussed before, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223715/typescript-type-narrowing-error-with-foreach) on SO.

The key point is this:

> One might ask compiler to infer what makeSideEffect does since we can provide
> the source of the function. However this is not practically feasible
> because of ambient function and (possibly polymorphic) recursion.
> Compiler will be trapped in infinite loops if we instruct it to infer
> arbitrary deep functions, as halting problem per se.
>
> So a realistic compiler must guess what a function does by a
> consistent strategy. Naturally we have two alternatives:
>
> Assume every function does not have relevant side effect: e.g.
> assignment like a = null. We call this optimistic. Assume every
> function does have side effect. We call this strategy pessimistic.
> Spoiler: TypeScript uses optimistic strategy.

[Source](https://herringtondarkholme.github.io/2017/02/04/flow-sensitive/)

In other words, TS will not make assumptions about what is in your map callback, including whether it has made a valid assignment in your case.

Edit: Your more detailed code illustrates the issue.  TS will not analyze your callback code to determine information about your global variable.

Given your code, I don't think an imperative solution is probably the way to go.  An immutable, functional solution like the on proposed in the other answer is probably better, i.e., return the values you want rather than assigning to a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to find an element which exists in an array - even in a possibly-nested array - you can make a recursive function that *returns* the result when found, so that the nested found directory can be recursively returned up to the initial caller:

```
const findName = (
    parentDir: Directory,
    nameToFind: string,
): Directory | void => {
    if (parentDir.name === nameToFind) {
        return parentDir;
    }
    for (const child of parentDir.children) {
        const possibleResult = findName(child, nameToFind);
        if (possibleResult) {
            return possibleResult;
        }
    }
};

const photosDir = findName(rootDirectory, 'photos');
```

Now `photosDir` will either be a `Directory` or void if none was found.

Comment: OK, I understand, I have to change a little the way how I write the code.