# Type narrowing not working in a factory function

Tags: typescript, narrowing

Why does TypeScript seem to lose its type narrowing in the return value of this function that returns a function?

```js
function foo(x: number | string) {
  if (typeof x === 'number') x = 'foo'
  x.toUpperCase()  // No problem
  return () => {
    x.toUpperCase()  // Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'string | number' - ts(2339)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a known issue on typescript, the type narrowing is lost inside the nested functions you need to add the checks inside as well

Comment: Also, please don't assign to function arguments, that's just *asking* for trouble

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63223715/3001761

Comment: Narrowing isn't carried over into functions since the function/closure could be executed at a point in which the narrowed types would be wrong. For example, consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wvk3Rw). If TS would allow this, then you would run into these kinds of problems. "Why can't TS statically check if the narrowing might be invalidated?" - because TS won't run your code to find out. It's not feasible to implement static type checking of this kind either.

Comment: The canonical issue in GitHub is [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).