# Different type narrowing behaviors between regular functions and function expressions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```js
function foo(item: string | null) {
  if (!item) return null
  return () => {
    function regular() {
      return item
    }
    const arrow = () => item
    console.log(regular().toLowerCase()) // Error: Object is possibly 'null'.
    console.log(arrow().toLowerCase()) // Pass
  }
}
```

[Playground Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUMoFMC2AuRAZygCcYwBzRAH0TBABsGBKRAbwChFEZhE0AhJlysSWKCBJJ6TLojESp-VgF4AfOzndQkWAnlYKjAIYk0rTtysHFSYTi2IAvo4gJiiUyTgB3RCuV-DXtXdzgGLAA6BjgKNDEjBlNzSKg4ABlfLBIAYWNCLHNmULBCcKiYuK9fFLTMn2y8gqK5FxcgA)

In function `foo` I wrote two nested functions. One is a regular function and the other is an arrow function. While I expect both values returned should be type narrowed to `string`, the fact is `regular()` got type `string | null`.

At first I thought it may be due to function param `item` is mutable. (Mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)) So I manually convert it to const, but it still has the same problem:

```js
function foo(item: string | null) {
  const itemCopy = item // Make sure TypeScript know it is immutable
  if (!itemCopy) return null
  return () => {
    function regular() {
      return itemCopy
    }
    const arrow = () => itemCopy
    console.log(regular().toLowerCase()) // Error: Object is possibly 'null'.
    console.log(arrow().toLowerCase()) // Pass
  }
}
```

[Playground Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUMoFMC2AuRAZygCcYwBzRAH0TBABsGBKRAbwChFEIFjFMuAMJwADgE9EAXgHYcXAcERoAhIJwiJrEliggSSekwU69B5aykA+dgu6hIsBIh0VGAQxJpWnbn5e6+kjqmuJ2iAC+4bxg-J4kcADu0hbSNiFiYf4xhHAMWAB0DHAUaK4eXswFUHAAMklYJELuhFjezNF8eYXFpfFJ3tV1DU0tbcwd3FFRQA)

Also mention it seems to be not related with arrow functions. Changing the arrow function into a regular function expression will also show the same behavior.

```js
function foo(item: string | null) {
  if (!item) return null
  return () => {
    function regular() {
      return item
    }
    const exp = function () { // Now the only difference is one is function expression while the other is not.
      return item
    }
    console.log(regular().toLowerCase()) // Error: Object is possibly 'null'.
    console.log(exp().toLowerCase()) // Pass
  }
}
```

[Playground Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUMoFMC2AuRAZygCcYwBzRAH0TBABsGBKRAbwChFEZhE0AhJlysSWKCBJJ6TLojESp-VgF4AfOzndQkWAnlYKjAIYk0rTtysHFSYTi2IAvo4gJiiLAA8ADohXI4NDwSOaa1twKknbYDtYu1m5ghHAMWAB0DHAUaGJGDKbm6VBwADJwAO5YJADCxoRY5syu7qkZWTnePkUl5VW19Y3MzdwuLkA)

So why is that? Is this behavior intended by design?

Comment: Looks like [ms/TS#36436](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36436) although I haven't figured out if this case is definitely a bug.  Function statements are hoisted and function expressions are not, so that explains a difference in control flow analysis behavior... whether or not it's *intended* is still a mystery to me.  I'll look later when I get a chance

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for providing this link! Seems like related with [#36436](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36436) and [#32300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32300). Also found this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32300#issuecomment-509406311). So this is due function "expressions" instead of "arrow" functions. I'll change my post for a more accurate description.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76036272/type-narrowing-not-working-in-a-factory-function.

Comment: Specifically, the comment by katniss: "Narrowing isn't carried over into functions since the function/closure could be executed at a point in which the narrowed types would be wrong."

Comment: @ddastrodd But in the seconds example in my post, I manually convert the value to a constant. I thought TypeScript should know the value and type will not change, but actually it didn't work. What's more, it can't explain the inconsistency between normal functions and function expressions. 

Comment: Also I found a very interesting example: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUMoFMC2AuRAZygCcYwBzRAH0TBABsGBKRAbwChFEZhE0AhJlysSWKCBJJ6TLogD08xAEZA8H+BjgkQBJPgE84IRGJxwAblkRwSiCHBw4sYKIigALGIUQADbMS-JwaHgwOVBIWAQXLGI0Vk5ubmEcRABeOkYGOQBfOTEJKX5WFIA+djluMKDIsQpGAEMSWLKEhLzJJCTyxByW2zBiRCwADwAHVIDw4MLmlqNxdp5sHC6ehL7COAYsADoGOAo0GvrG5m2oOAAZOAB3LBIAYTrCLFjmLvXNnb2D4ZHYs8uNzuj2erwUSgATBpEAAVVyOFzuTwMcgWa4wJiIa5WADW2Q4OSAA)
Seems like TypeScript is smart enough to figure out a whether a variable will be modify somewhere. (Apply to function expressions only)

Comment: The full gamut of narrowing behavior in TS is hard to describe comprehensively; the general issue with closed-over variables is discussed at [ms/TS#998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998), but there are many interesting seeming exceptions to the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working as intended, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#32300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32300). Fundamentally, [function *declarations*/*statements*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) behave differently from [function *expressions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) in that function declarations are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#hoisting).  Hoisted function declarations can be called earlier than their definitions appear in the code, while non-hoisted function expressions cannot:

```
function foo(item: string | null) {
  if (!item) return null
  return () => {
    regular(); // okay
    exp(); // error
    function regular() {
      return item
    }
    const exp = function () {
      return item
    }
  }
}
```

That means there are different implications for [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  It looks like for hoisted functions TypeScript just gives up and pessimistically assumes that any closed-over variables have not been narrowed, while for function expressions it optimistically assumes any narrowing from earlier persists.  It's not clear that either of these behaviors is "correct", but it's definitely behaving as designed.

The general issue of narrowing in the face of closed-over variables is discussed in depth in [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998). TypeScript makes a lot of simplifying assumptions that work well enough in many situations but exhibit  unfortunate false negatives and false positives in edge cases.  Usually when one finds an inconsistency it turns out not to be a bug but a design choice with downsides.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUMoFMC2AuRAZygCcYwBzRAH0TBABsGBKRAbwChFEZhE0AhJlysSWKCBJJ6TLojESp-VgF4AfOzncxFRgEMSaZgG5EAejOI4Aaz0BPLYiwAPAA5HTFpyRJwSj0EhYBHksXQYDI01uGNDFJGEcRwBfRwgEYic3RBVkcGh4JCjOWO1xSQTsJNjU2PSwQjgGLAA6BjgKNB19Q2YWqDgAGTgAdywSAGE9QiwjZjSMptb2zpd3PoHhscnp2eZ57lTUjgAjSJNzSz0mUawAEwAaRBOQKEQAFQARAC1nvTuwFhCIQOPVMs4cogAIzGDiBAohM69aKIMFLNodNDOfpwABiMGc9zmsOSQA)