# TS complains about potential null but I did check the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

On line 5 TS complains about the fact that `gameInstanceContext.gameInstance` might be null. On line 3 it does not complain. Since I checked its value on line 1, I expect TS to understand that the value is not falsy, and I do not understand why it complains on line 5.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!gameInstanceContext.gameInstance) return

        console.log(gameInstanceContext.gameInstance.players) // TS does not complain
        const ft = () => {
            console.log(gameInstanceContext.gameInstance.players) // TS complains
        }

        ft()
    }, [gameInstanceContext.gameInstance])
```

`gameInstanceContext.gameInstance`'s type is `TGameInstance | null | undefined`.

Why does TS complain about gameInstanceContext.gameInstance being potentially null or undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a lambda function which can potentially be used in another context where the if check is not done beforehand, therefore TS cannot assume that it cannot be null or undefined.

Comment: I think you're right, though if the code really looks like what's posted here it *could* be possible for Typescript to take note of the symbol `ft` going out of scope with that one call, and that call happens in the same context (after the `if` test) as the first access before the inner function declaration.

Comment: This is a correct answer but is fairly scant on details and/or supporting documentation.  I'd suggest at least including a link to [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) here.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77550074/ts-complains-about-potential-null-but-i-did-check-the-value#comment136716055_77550082) @jcalz This is an exact dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76036272/438273, right?

Comment: I don't know about "exact" but yeah, it's probably a duplicate question.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I should have given more insights, however, I wasn't sure how to, since the answer is a combination of an extended amount of js and ts concepts. The thread you referred to provides a lot of detail, especially this answer: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998#issuecomment-236446974